# what is meant by the notation "U+" when discussing Unicode encoding?

Tags: unicode, unicode-string

i realize this is pretty basic, as i am reading about Unicode in Wikipedia and wherever it points.  but this "U+0000" semantic is not completely explained.  it appears to me that "U" always equals 0.

why is that "U+" part of the notation?  what exactly does it mean? (it appears to be some base value, but i cannot understand when or why it is ever non-zero.)

also, if i receive a string of text from some other source, how do i know if that string is encoded UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32?  is there some way i can automatically determine that by context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. From Wikipedia, article [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), section [Architecture and Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology):

   > Unicode defines a codespace of 1,114,112 code points in the range 0 to 10FFFF (hexadecimal). Normally a Unicode code point is referred to by writing "U+" followed by its hexadecimal number. For code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), four digits are used (e.g., U+0058 for the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X); for code points outside the BMP, five or six digits are used.

   This convention was introduced so that the readers understand that the code point is specifically a *Unicode* code point. For example, the letter `ă` (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH BREVE) is U+0103; in Code Page 852 it has the code 0xC7, in Code Page 1250 it has the code 0xE3, but when I write U+0103 everybody understands that I mean the Unicode code point and they can look it up.
2. For languages written with the Latin alphabet, UTF-16 and UTF-32 strings will most likely contain lots and lots of bytes with the value 0, which should not appear in UTF-8 encoded strings. By looking at *which* bytes are zero you can also infer the byte order of UTF-16 and UTF-32 strings, even in the absence of a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

   So for example if you get the bytes

   ```
    0xC3 0x89 0x70 0xC3 0xA9 0x65
   ```

   this is most likely `Épée` in UTF-8 encoding. In little-endian UTF-16 this would be

   ```
    0x00 0xC9 0x00 0x70 0x00 0xE9 0x00 0x65
   ```

   (Note how every even-numbered byte is zero.)

Comment: thanks, i started discovering some of this myself, but this answer is very helpful.

Comment: so i learned that the "U" isn't added to anything, it's just a notation similar to "`0x`" preceding hexadecimal or "`H`" following (that seems to be deprecated, thankfully).  and it also looks like everything i am seeing, in terms of texts strings coming in is UTF-8.  so **no** character that is outside of the 7-bit range of ASCII is encoded as a single byte.  e.g. the ¢ character is never a single byte of `0xA2` in UTF-8.  if you want ¢ in UTF-8, it must be encoded as two bytes `0xC2A2`.  so with UTF-8, there is no *"extended ASCII"*.  and of those characters have to be two or more bytes.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: yes, some languages uses the escape notation \u1234 (and possibly \U103456). Note: U+XXXX (and \u) is decoded, because it is a logical (and abstract) representation of the character: it indicates a character on the unicode tables, without telling us how it will be put as bytes. Instead 0xAA is encoded, so a physical representation of the bytes.